# Find the sum of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 1/[(r+2k+2)(s+2k+2)]$

Tags: sequences-and-series

\begin{align}
 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(r+2k+2)(s+2k+2)} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(r+2m)(s+2m)}
\end{align}

$r>s>0$. $r$ is a odd number, but I don't think this gonna be relevant. The fact that $r>s$ is given because it's a telescopic series (I think).

I wanted to know where does this series converge to and what happens when $r$ is odd and $s$ is either odd or even, but I don't know how to evaluate this sum.

Comment: Do you know about partial fractions?

Comment: Not really, but I will look it up.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac1{(r+2m)(s+2m)}=\frac1{r-s}\left(\frac1{s+2m}-\frac1{r+2m}\right).$$
If the difference of $r$ and $s$ is an even integer, the sum will telescope.
In general, if $r-s$ is odd, or not an integer, this won't work.

In these cases use the identity involving the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)
$$\frac{1}{x}=\psi(x+1)-\psi(x).$$
One gets
$$\sum_{m=1}^M\frac1{(r+2m)(s+2m)}=\frac{\psi(s/2+M+1)-\psi(s/2+1)
-\psi(r/2+M+1)+\psi(r/2+1)}{2(r-s)}.$$
In the limit,
$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{(r+2m)(s+2m)}=\frac{\psi(r/2+1)
-\psi(s/2+1)}{2(r-s)}.$$

Comment: Is there another way rather than using the digamma function?

Comment: If $r$ and $s$ are integers of different parity, you can reduce to the case $(r,s)=(2,1)$, which is a standard series.

Comment: @Pinteco. Use harmonic numbers instead if you prefer $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{(r+2m)(s+2m)}=\frac{\psi(r/2+1)
-\psi(s/2+1)}{2(r-s)}=\frac{H_{\frac{r}{2}}-H_{\frac{s}{2}}}{2( r- s)}$$