# Evaluate $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2m+s}\frac{1}{2m+r}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$S = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2m+s}\frac{1}{2m+r}$

$r>s>0$ and both $r,s$ integers.

write $x=2m+s$ and $y=r-s$.
\begin{align}
&S = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2m+s}\frac{1}{2m+r} = 
\sum_{x=s+2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{x+y} =
 \sum_{x=s+2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{xy} - \frac{1}{y(x+y)} \right)=\\ 
&\frac{1}{y}\sum_{x=s+2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+y} \right)
= \frac{1}{r-s}\sum_{x=s+2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+r-s} \right)
\end{align}

From this post [Evaluating the sum (telescoping series): $\sum_{k=s+1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+r-s}\right)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948848/evaluating-the-sum-telescoping-series-sum-k-s1-infty-left-frac1k)

\begin{align}
S = \frac{1}{r-s}\sum_{x=s+2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+r-s} \right)
=\frac{1}{r-s} \left( \frac{1}{s+2} + \frac{1}{s+3} \cdots + \frac{1}{r}\right)
\end{align}

Is the above correct? I asked this another day but I could understand nothing of the answers.

Another thing is: I assumed that both $r,s$ are integers, but, If I assumed to be both odd numbers, would something change?

I did some tests in Wolfram, and it seems that for both $r,s$ odd integers and $r>s>0$, the sum $S$ will be a rational number.

This is a follow up question to: [Find the sum of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 1/[(r+2k+2)(s+2k+2)]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954661/find-the-sum-of-sum-k-0-infty-1-r2k2s2k2)

The answer in the link use the Digamma function. I wanted to know If the answer in the current post is correct.

Comment: Has this question recently been asked before?  I also remember a solution using the property of Digamma function and also a hint in comments using the harmonic numbers.

Comment: Yes, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954661/find-the-sum-of-sum-k-0-infty-1-r2k2s2k2. I don't know this Digamma function or the harmonic numbers very well so I did the above. After reading the post I think the above is only correct when $r,s$ are both odd. Quoting the other user: "If the difference of r and s is an even integer, the sum will telescope. In general, if r−s is odd, or not an integer, this won't work."

Comment: @ Leucippus I made that question and linked above. I could understand nothing. This is a follow up question and wanted to see if what I did is correct.